# s3 file read in DSE Spark job fails

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, datastax-enterprise

I am using dse 5.1.0 (packaged with spark 2.0.2.6 and scala 2.11.8).
Trying to run a spark job that reads file in s3 bucket(in Mumbai region).
Getting "400: Bad Request" error.
If same job is run on apache spark, works fine.
Tested following in dse/apache spark shell, fails in dse.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "ACCESSKEY")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "SECRETACCESSKEY")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")
System.setProperty("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
val a = sc.textFile("s3a://MUMBAI_REGION_BUCKET/FILE")
a.count
```

Error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: A716DEAAE05C3F2F, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Bad Request
```

Comment: Have you considered the approach outline in this article here using the env variables to old the AWS login credentials? http://www.sparktutorials.net/Reading+and+Writing+S3+Data+with+Apache+Spark